# Search for redirected website path

Tags: java, redirect, web, path

I have two websites, A and B. When I open website A, I am redirected to website B automatically.

What is the function with which I can check what was the full path of website A from which was the redirect?

I was trying to start with:

> 

```
        logger.info(request.getPathInfo());
        logger.info(request.getPathTranslated());
        logger.info(request.getServletPath());
        logger.info(request.getLocalName());
        logger.info(request.getRemoteAddr());
        logger.info(request.getRemoteHost());
        logger.info(request.getRequestURI());
        logger.info(request.getServerName());
```

but none of them is correct.

For redirecting I use ***response.sendRedirect*** inside Controller.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using the optional *[referer](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.36)* header:

```
request.getHeader("referer");
```

But it is important to note that this may not always be populated (specifically IE).

A better solution, if you are in control of both of the websites, is to pass the value somehow when you are doing the redirect. For example, as a GET or POST parameter.

Edit:

As suggested above, you can append query strings to your redirect URL. For example, you might try something like this:

```
String redirectUrl = "http://my.redirect.com/";

redirectUrl += "?referer=";
redirectUrl += URLEncoder.encode(request.getRequestURL().toString(), "UTF-8");
```

Then you can just pull this out of the request on the other side.

Use this as a starting point. You may need to manually append other query parameters that may not be part of the `getRequestURL()` output.

Comment: FYI to anyone wondering: the header name is supposed to be misspelled. It's not exactly intentional, but there was a mistake in the first version of the HTTP spec, and now we're stuck with it.

Comment: Thank's for help - but as i know the request.getHeader("referer") works only if i click on a link and then i will be redirected. But i i use response.sendRedirect inside of Controller, then this method give me nothing :(

Answer (score 1):

None of these would get you the page that redirected you to the current page. What you can try is:

```
String refererPage = request.getHeader("referer");
```

However keep in mind that this is also browser dependent and may not always be present.

Comment: Thank's for help - but as i know the request.getHeader("referer") works only if i click on a link and then i will be redirected. But i i use response.sendRedirect inside of Controller, then this method give me nothing :(

Comment: If that the case you have 2 options of sending across referral URL: `1. Sending it as GET query parameter 2. Set a cookie (will only work within sister domains)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
request.getHeader("referer");
```

Comment: Thank's for help - but as i know the request.getHeader("referer") works only if i click on a link and then i will be redirected. But i i use response.sendRedirect inside of Controller, then this method give me nothing :(

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
request.getHeader("referer");
```